# Socket.io, How to know from which route socket disconnects?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, frontend, backend

I'm writing a multiplayer game. I want to check if a player left the game room so they game won't start unless there are two people.
**Server:**

```
         socket.on('disconnect', () => {
         if (rooms.find('ownerName', nickname)) {
             rooms.delete(nickname);
        }
         console.log(nickname, 'Disconnected!')
         // Emit an event when a member leaves a room
        rooms.array().forEach(o => {
            for (let p of [o.players.array()]) {
                console.log(p.nickname === nickname)
                if (p[0].nickname === nickname) {
                    let roomInstance = rooms.get(o.ownerName);

                    if (roomInstance) {
                        roomInstance.players.delete(p[0].nickname);
                        const playersCount = roomInstance.players.size;
                        console.log('Emitting ' + `room player left ${o.ownerName}`)
                        return io.sockets.emit(`room player left ${o.ownerName}`, p.nickname, playersCount);
                    }

                }
            }

        });

        lobbyMembers.delete(nickname);
    });
```

Ok so, the disconnect event emits when a member from the lobby route is disconnecting
**Lobby frontend:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       const socket = io.connect();
        let nickname = "<%= nickname %>"
        socket.emit('new lobby member', nickname)

        //TODO: If owner don't show button
        $('#newRoomBtn').click(function(event) {
            $('#newRoomBtn').fadeOut('fast');
            socket.emit('new room', nickname);
        });

        socket.on('new room', owner => {
            $("#gamesTable tr:last")
                .after("<tr><th><%= rooms.size + 1 %></th><th>" + owner.nickname + `</th><th><a class="button" href="game/${owner.nickname}">join</a></th>`);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to check if the player is disconnecting from the Room route
Room **frontend:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       const socket = io.connect();

       let newRoomPlayerEvent = 'new room player <%= room.owner.nickname %>';
       let roomPlayerLeft = 'room player left <%= room.owner.nickname %>';

        const room = <%- JSON.stringify(room) %>
       socket.emit('new room player', room, "<%= nickname %>")

       socket.on(newRoomPlayerEvent, function(player, playersCount) {
            const Heading = playersCount >= 2 ? "Press ready" : `Waiting for an opponent! (${playersCount})`
            if (playersCount >= 2) $('#readyButton').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.headingRoom').html(`<h2 class='headingRoom centered is-size-3'>${Heading}</h2>`);
        });

        socket.on(roomPlayerLeft, function(player, playersCount) {
            console.log(player)
            const Heading = playersCount >= 2 ? "Press ready" : `Waiting for an opponent! (${playersCount})`
            if (playersCount < 2) $('#readyButton').fadeOut('slow');
            if (playersCount <= 2) $('#readyButton').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.headingRoom').html(`<h2 class='headingRoom centered is-size-3'>${Heading}</h2>`);
        });

        $('#readyButton').click(function() {
            console.log(<%- JSON.stringify([...players.entries()].reduce((acc, val) => ((acc[val[0]] = val[1]), acc), {})) %>)
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you want to find out if a user left the lobby?

Comment: @messerbill Actually, I want to find out if a user left a room

Comment: the `socket.on('disconnect', ` handler will notice each disconnect from each room

Comment: @messerbill Yes, but it fires for lobby only. I don't know why

Comment: `socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log("hello"))` this does not work for each disconnect?